# Media Player: Stream from Database

Tags: database, audio, stream, media-player, android-contentprovider

in short: i have some audio files in my local sqlitedatabse and want to play with with the native media player from android. 
reffered to the documentation i can play an audio either by placing my audio file on the sd card or by streaming from server or by an URI.

There is no way to play an audio file by giving an byte array to the media player.

so my solution would be to build an CONTENTPROVIDER which lets my media player access the audio file in the database via an URI. I came up with that idea through this tutorial

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Is this possible? Are there better ways to implement my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are proposing creating an artificial URL that you are then passing to the android system to be read, and you supply the data backing the URL by reading it from SQLite. That will probably work, and it solves some issues with content decoding, but it requires the creation of awkward URLs and sockets within the system. All that might not be the most reliable or efficient way to go.

The alternative is to decode the data yourself into PCM, and supply it to Android via an [Audio Track](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html). This would be superior because you aren't trying to create a hacked (and artificial) URL just to pipe a stream of data through, but it may require you to parse the data yourself and convert it to PCM. Depending on what formats you have in your database, this may be difficult and not worth it because Android libraries for these kinds of conversions are not as accessible. So, which way is *best* depends on your goals, but I think those are your two options.